# Number of working days between two dates in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion

`DateDiff()` gives me the number of calendar dates between two dates. How can I get the number of working days (excluding Sat/Sun)?

Comment: Matt told you how to count weekdays only.  Holidays are a different matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to work anything out, the work's already been done for you. There's a UDF for this on CFLib: [`businessDaysBetween()`](http://www.cflib.org/udf/businessDaysBetween).

That said, the algorithm used there requires looping, which I don't think you should need. It should just be something like the `dateDiff()` in weeks between the two dates, multiplied by five, with some offsetting for the day of the week that the start and end dates fall on.

I'm tied up with something else at the mo', but if I get a moment will knock a better function out and update the one on CFLib, reporting back here when done.

Comment: @MotoTribe - Yep, cflib.org is always a good place to check. Usually it already has a function that does what you need - or at least one that can be used as a starting point.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [dayOfWeek](https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/DayOfWeek) and make sure it's not 1 or 7 and you loop through the dates

```
  days = 0;    
  while (date1 LT date2) {
    date1 = dateAdd('d',1,date1);
    if(NOT listFind('1,7',dayOfWeek(date1))) {
      days++;
    }
  }
```